# Finding closest Entity to Player in Libgdx Java

Tags: java, libgdx

**I am aware of Box2D and can NOT use it for this assignment**

Now, I am trying to find the closest `Entity` to my player. This is so the collision detection can focus on just the closest entity instead of all of them at once. I thought the way I did this was correct, but there seems to be some error. 
First let me show you some images of the project, here is an image of the player correctly noticing the closest Entity.

[image]

As you can see, it perfectly finds the closest Entity(the yellow lines point to the closest side of Entity)

Before I show the code, let me explain a few variables in the code and what it is doing. All `Entity`'s are grabbed from the `EntityStage`. They are all stored in a `HashMap`. I use a key to find the closest entity on x and y axis. Then I see which is closer altogether at the end. `keyX` is the key for the closest entity on x-axis and `keyY` for y-axis.

```
public Entity player, entity;
private Vector2 tmpVec = new Vector2(), finKeyX = new Vector2(), finKeyY = new Vector2();
private Vector2 finalVec = new Vector2();
public void getClosestEntity(){

    entityHash = entityStage.getMap();

    player = entityHash.get("player");
    String finalKey = "";
    String keyX = "", keyY = "";
    for(String key : entityHash.keySet())
        if(!key.equals("player"))
        keyX = keyY = key;
    for(String key : entityHash.keySet()){
        for(int i = 0; i < entityHash.size(); i++){
            if(!key.equals(Player.KEY)){
                entity = entityHash.get(key);

                tmpVec.x = Math.abs(entity.getPosition().x - player.getPosition().x);
                tmpVec.y = Math.abs(entity.getPosition().y - player.getPosition().y);




                if(Math.abs(entityHash.get(keyX).getPosition().x - player.getPosition().x) > tmpVec.x){
                    keyX = key;
                }

                if(Math.abs(entityHash.get(keyY).getPosition().x - player.getPosition().x) > tmpVec.y){
                    keyY = key;
            }
            }
        }

    }

    if(keyX.equals(keyY)){
        finalKey = keyX;
    }
    finKeyX = entityHash.get(keyX).getPosition();
    finKeyY = entityHash.get(keyY).getPosition();

    // if KeyX is closer on X
    if(Math.abs(finKeyX.x - player.getPosition().x) < Math.abs(finKeyY.x - player.getPosition().x)){
        //If keyX is close on Y
        if(Math.abs(finKeyX.y - player.getPosition().y) < Math.abs(finKeyY.y - player.getPosition().y)){
            finalKey = keyX;
            //if keyY is closer on Y
        }else{
            if(Math.abs(finKeyX.x - finKeyX.y) < Math.abs(finKeyY.y - finKeyY.x)){
                finalKey = keyX;
            }else
                finalKey = keyY;
        }

        //if KeyY is closer on X
    }else{
        //if KeyY is closer on Y
        if(Math.abs(finKeyX.y - player.getPosition().y) > Math.abs(finKeyY.y - player.getPosition().y)){
            finalKey = keyY;
            //if KeyX is closer on Y
        }else{

            if(Math.abs(finKeyX.x - finKeyX.y) < Math.abs(finKeyY.y - finKeyY.x)){
                finalKey = keyY;
            }else
                finalKey = keyX;
        }

    }
```

However, for some reason this happens.

[image]

When I go directly under the other entity, it recognizes the further entity therefor making the player fall through the ground. I have spent hours trying to see where I went wrong in the above code and I just can't seem to find why it is recognizing the top entity as the closest. Any help in this regard is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you have coordinates you can create a vector between them. The length of that vector is the distance. Something like this:

```
Vector2 source = player.getPosition();
Vector2 target = someEntity.getPosition();

Vector2 between = source.cpy().sub(target);
float distance = between.dst();
```

Now put it in a loop of available entities and your done. Anyway, I would not even worry about the closest entity, just parse the entities when there distance tells you they might intersect. If you have a lot of entities you might want to add "areas" and only test those in the same area.